# Not able to recover local changes after "git stash"

Tags: git

I made some changes locally in excel sheet and then saved & closed it, after that I opened git and hit the command `git stash` and then my local changes got reset, now I want my old excel sheet which was updated earlier in my local but not able to get it

I tried `git stash list` but nothing is coming
I tried `git stash apply`/ `git stash pop` but getting `error- refs/stash@{0} is not a valid reference`

I tried 
`$ git fsck --unreachable | grep commit | cut -d ' ' -f3 | xargs git log --merges --no-walk`

Comment: Just running `git stash apply` or `git stash pop` once should have reapplied your work.  Are you sure that you are not leaving out any other step you might have taken?

Comment: Yes,I tried few below step as well..

Comment: 1.$ git stash apply
error: Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by merge:
        Keyword-Driven-Framework-BookService-readyapi-project.xml
Please commit your changes or stash them before you merge.
Aborting

Comment: 2 - $ git stash drop
Dropped refs/stash@{0} (ec182bb6d7f1ae55665128bac1f0831363789b06)
3.$ git stash list
stash@{0}: WIP on BookService_Automation: 7260750f updated the data

Comment: Why did you drop the stash?

Comment: Someone suggested to do git stash apply and then stash drop.. that's why I did it.
Is there any way to recover??